# How to understand Workbox Config must be set before accessing workbox.* modules?

Tags: nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps, workbox

Background(problem):

I use workbox in my web application (nuxt.js + node.js), in my sw.js, import workbox as follow:

```js
importScripts('/local_path/workbox-sw.js');
workbox.setConfig({
  debug: false,
  modulePathPrefix: '/local_path/workbox/3.3.0/'
});
```

howerver, i got error: "Config must be set before accessing workbox.* modules"

I found it in workbox-sw.js, error throwed from setConfig,
[if(this.Ct)throw new Error("Config must be set before accessing workbox.* modules")]
We can see [this.Ct] be set as [!0] when loadModdule be called in constructor(), so when call workbox.setConfig, [this.Ct] always be [!0]?
Anybody could help me to understand it, thanks firstly!

```js
self.workbox=new class{
        constructor(){
            console.log('log1:' + self.location.hostname)
            return this.v={},
                this.Pt={debug:"localhost"===self.location.hostname,modulePathPrefix:null,modulePathCb:null},
                this.$t=this.Pt.debug?"dev":"prod",
                this.Ct=!1,
                new Proxy(this,{get(e,s){if(e[s])return e[s];const o=t[s];
                    return o&&e.loadModule("workbox-"+o),e[s]}})
        }

        setConfig(t={}){
            console.log('log3:' + this.Pt.modulePathPrefix)
            if(this.Ct)throw new Error("Config must be set before accessing workbox.* modules");
            Object.assign(this.Pt,t),this.$t=this.Pt.debug?"dev":"prod"
        }
        loadModule(t){
            const e=this.jt(t);
            try{
                importScripts(e),this.Ct=!0
            }catch(s){
                throw console.error(`Unable to import module '${t}' from '${e}'.`),s
            }
        }
....
}
```